# How can I modify Edm types in olingo by mapping in Olingo

Tags: jpa, olingo

In MySQL the column that are boolean are modeled via `bit(1)` or `byte(1)`.

When I am using Olingo/Jpa beside MySQL and generate the entities in the Eclipse, it will assign type `byte` to these columns. It means in the metadata we will have something like this:

```
<Property Name="Deleted" Type="Edm.Byte" Nullable="false"/>
```

How can I modify the EDM type like the following?

```
<Property Name="Deleted" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false"/>
```

What I want to do is to do this modification with a mapping file, something like what explained [here](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/tutorials/jparedefinemetadata.html). *(By this tutorial we can only change the names and not the types!)*

Please note that I make `eclipselink-orm.xml` also automatically. I don't want to modify this file but it seems the type can be changed there as it has a line like this:

```
<basic name="deleted" attribute-type="byte">
```

However I don't want to modify this file each time while I generate it via Eclipse. Is there anyway that I extend some attributes there and inherent the rests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible by olingo mapping file. This file is used only for renaming or exclusing the attributes or sets. We need to generate `eclipselink-orm.xml` file. You don't need to do the steps by hand. You can easily select the `Dynamic Entities from Tables` menu from JPA menu like this wizard:

[image]

And then define the suitable `mapping types` for the intended columns as follows in the last step of the wizard.

[image]

**For example here in the above figure I defined the `boolean` for column `deleted` for table `conditions` or the entity `condition`!**